# WZ Factorization

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matlab, matrix-decomposition

The MATLAB code below is to factorize a non-singular matrix into Z-matrix via WZ-factorization. However, I got the error message "Not enough input arguments".

```
function coder=WZfactorization(A)
  A=input('matrix A =');
  n=size(A);
   for k =1:n/2-1
     k2 = n-k-1;
    det = A(k,k)*A(k2,k2)-A(k2,k)*A(k,k2);
   for i=k+1:k2-1
    w(i,k) = (A(k2,k)*A(i,k2)-A(k2,k2)*A(i,k))/det;
    w(i,k2) = (A(k,k2)*A(i,k)-A(k,k)*A(i,k2))/det;
  for j = k+1 : k2-1
    A(i,j) = A(i,j)+w(i,k)*A(k,j)+w(i,k2)*A(k2,j);
    end
  end
end
  A(i,j)=Z;
end
```

For instance the code should factorize
$A=\left(
\begin{array}{cccccc}
2  &  1  &   3  &-6 & 3 &3       \\
10  &  6  &   9  &-13 & 10 &14       \\
12  &  13  &   12  &-13 & 19 &17       \\
8  &  10  &   11  &-4 & 12 &11       \\ 
12  &  8  &   13  &-20 & 14 &17       \\
3  &  1  &   1  &-1 & 1 &4       
\end{array}\right)$
$\qquad$ to $\qquad$
$Z =\left(
\begin{array}{cccc}
2  &  1  &   3  &-6 & 3 &3       \\
0  &  2  &   1  &1 & 2 &0       \\
0  &  0  &   -4  &6 & 0 &0       \\
0&  0  &   2  &2 & 0 &0       \\
0  &  3  &   2  &0 & 3 &0       \\
3  &  1  &   1  &-1 & 1 &4 
\end{array}\right)$

Another example is that the code should also factorize

$A=\left(
\begin{array}{cccc}
5  &  4  &   1   & 1       \\
4   &  5   &  1      &    1  \\
1&1&4&2   \\
1&1&2&4   
\end{array}\right)$
$\qquad$ to $\qquad$
$Z =\left(
\begin{array}{cccc}
5  &  4  &   1   & 1       \\
0   &  1.7895   &  1.1053   &   0\\
0&0.1053&2.9474&0    \\
1&1&2&4
\end{array}\right)$

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Potential mistakes:

Note that in your Matlab code, $w$ and $Z$ are your input rather than your output.

I don't see $w$ are being used as an input

Also, coder, $wk1$, and $wk2$ are not defined in your code. Are they global variables or are those syntax error?

When you call your function as the way it is written now, it should be of the form of

$$coder=WZfactorization(w,Z)$$

what you want perhaps is

$$coder=WZfactorization()$$

or personally I prefer $$coder=WZfactorization(A)$$ rather than asking for user input.

Note taht coder is not assigned in your current code.

Comment: 1. $w$ and $Z$ are output not input

Comment: I think your matlab code is not aware of that. how did you call your function?

Comment: I have made some correction according to your suggestions. Please recheck the edited code

Comment: you might want to omit the line A=input('matrix A =') now. Also, you have to assign value to coder. Also another syntax error "k=k="

Comment: Also $A(i,j)=Z$ is outside all the loop which I think this might not intended.

Comment: Thank you for all the suggestions. What should I do with $A(i,j)=Z$ ? Should I remove it.                                                                                         "you have to assign value to coder" please what do you mean                      "k=k=" is corrected now

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/59955/discussion-between-dupsy-and-siong-thye-goh).